# How to place the scrollbar outside of div?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar, overflow

I set `overflow: auto` on the `div`.
The `width` of the `div` is decreased when the `scrollbar` is displayed, but I want to maintain the width of `div`.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: The width of the div ***is*** maintained but the scroll bar possibly occupies this space. This is also browser dependent, i.e. like mobile browsers overlaying a scrollbar.

Comment: No, the width of the child element is reduced by the width of the scrollbar.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `overflow: scrollbar`, use `overflow: overlay` ([link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)):

> Behaves the same as auto, but with the scrollbars drawn on top of content instead of taking up space. Only supported in WebKit-based (e.g., Safari) and Blink-based (e.g., Chrome or Opera) browsers.

### Additionally

Scrollbar (`overflow: scrollbar`) is taking `div`s `width`, however, you can customize scrollbar, even hide it ([How to style scrollbar](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_scrollbar.asp)):

```css
body {
  height: 250vh;
}

/* width */
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px; /* you can shrink taken width */
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: transparent; 
}
 
/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: red; 
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #555; 
}
```